# Question regarding exchanging territory cards in Risk

Tags: risk

I am reading the [rules of Risk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoWwJ.jpg), and at the top of the second column (in `3. Exchanging Territory Cards`) it says that "if you hold 5 or more cards, you MUST exchange one or more sets on your turn". A "set" has been explained to be 3 cards with the same insignia, where a wild card can be used as any of the 3 insignias.

If for example I had these 5 cards - Infantry, Infantry, Artillery, Artilley, Cavalry - then I do not have a set of any insignias, but am forced to swap a set as I have 5 cards. The same could occur if I had 6 cards, 2 of each insignia and no wild cards.

Where am I going wrong in understanding this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the [rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/risk.pdf) (1993 standard Risk) on page 7 (emphasis mine):

> You are trying to collect sets of 3 cards in any of the following combinations:
>
> - 3 cards of same design (Infantry, Cavalry, or Artillery)
> - **1 each of 3 designs**
> - any 2 plus a “wild” card

This is verified in the rules you posted:

> A set is made up of 3 cards with the same Insignia..., OR 3 cards with one of each of the 3 Insignia...

In the case where you have "*Infantry, Infantry, Artillery, Artillery, Cavalry*," you will trade in "*Infantry, Artillery, Cavalry*" as a set.

Answer (score 5):

I just realised that a set can also be 1 of each of the Insignias

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15654)

Comment: @ToonKrijthe - This is an answer, albiet a brief one.